# asp.net core Logging not following the ConfigurationBuilder hierarchy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to configure the log level of an asp.net core application. I have this ConfigurationBuilder set up in my Startup class.

```
         var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile("ConfigFiles/appsettings.configs.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
```

And then in even though I configure the LogLevel in my "ConfigFiles/appsettings.configs.json" file, like this:

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  }
```

It is simply being ignored. Instead, it is always reading directly from "appsettings.json" (the root file), no matter what. 
I've even tried to comment out the line of code that configures it, and surprisingly it still reads from there. I know that because I deliberately inserted a bug in the LogLevel configuration, and it throws an error.
For the other configuration it works correctly, reading from both files. Looks like "Logging" mechanism statically points to the root appsettings.json file.
How do I make it to read from the other file, instead of the root?

Thank you

EDIT:
Framework Version: .net Core 3.0

Answer (score -1):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#json-configuration-provider):

> `AddJsonFile` is automatically called twice when you initialize a new
>   host builder with `CreateDefaultBuilder`. The method is called to load configuration from:
>
> appsettings.json – This file is read first. The environment version of the file can override the values provided by the appsettings.json file.
>
> appsettings.{Environment}.json – The environment version of the file is loaded based on the IHostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName.

There are two config files `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Development.json` which overrides settings in the base `appsettings.json` file. And system use it in development mode. You could change the default Loglevel in `appsettings.Development.json` file .

[image]

Comment: OP is not calling `CreateDefaultBuilder` so this answer is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Indeed it works if I change it in the "appsettings.Development.json" file, but that is not my point, because that means it still reads from the "root" file. The way I need it to work, I'd need it to be read from the file that is the the sub-folder. For everything that I've tried so far, it is looking like that is a bug in the Logging component, that is reading from the root directory, rather than using the Configuration that was done